# File is not imported in IDLE (Anaconda/Mac/IDLE)

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, python-idle

I installed Anaconda on my Mac
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXzVU.jpg)

and saved this file as 'stock' (file name) in 'Anaconda3' folder.

Then I tried to import this file
it comes like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v6iK.jpg)

what is the problem?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

If it it just called "stock", it would not work.

Python modules must end in .py, or a few other extensions, so try naming it "stock.py"

Comment: I tried but it comes out like this

Comment: >>> import stock.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import stock.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stock'

Comment: oh, also its still import stock, not import stock.py, and your welcome

Comment: Also, the file to be imported has to be in a directory in sys.path.  I don't know if this is true of the Anaconda3 directory.  Also, cut and paste text into your question instead of using an ephermeral image.